# Number of real solutions to $x^7 + 2x^5 + 3x^3 + 4x = 2018$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Find the number of real solutions of $x^7 + 2x^5 + 3x^3 + 4x = 2018$?

What is the general approach to solving this kind of questions? I am interested in the thought process.

---

Few of my thoughts after seeing this question:
since $x$ has all odd powers so, it can not have any negative solution. 
2018 is semiprime; not much progress here. We can sketch the curve but graphing a seven order polynomial is difficult.

Comment: Do you know differentiation?

Comment: yes, I know @badjohn

Comment: Try https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_rule_of_signs#Positive_roots

Comment: So, differentiate it and have a look at the result.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If $x\le 0$ the left hand side is negative therefore no solution. We suppose $x>0$ and we consider  $f(x)=x^7+2x^5+3x^3+4x$, then $f$ is the sum of increasing functions therefore increasing. Since  $f(0,\infty)=(0,\infty)$ this equation has only one solution.

---

This can be done by differentiation which give a more simple proof since the derivative is clearly positive.

Answer (score 4):

Render

$x^7+0x^6+2x^5+0x^4+3x^3+0x^2+4x-2018=0$

[Descartes' Rule of Signs](https://www.mathplanet.com/education/algebra-2/polynomial-functions/descartes-rule-of-sign) forces exactly one positive root and no negative roots.  That's it!